# Reading/writing Python dictionary to Redis cache on AWS crashes server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, redis, celery

I am developing a computation intensive django application. Using Celery, to perform time taking tasks, and using Redis as a broker, and for cache puposes.

Redis cache is used to share a large dictionary structure across celery tasks.

I have a rest api to frequently write/update a python dictionary in Redis cache (after 1 second). Each api call initiates a new task.

At localhost it all works good. But on Aws, the the elastic-beanstalk app crashes when run for sometime.

It does not crash when the dictionary structure is empty. Here is the code how I update the cache.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=Constants.REDIS_CACHE_ADDRESS, port=6379, db=0)
mydict_obj  = r.get("mydict")

if mydict_obj:

    mydict = eval(str(mydict_obj))
else:
    mydict = {}


for hash_instance in all_hashes:

    if hash_instance[1] in mydict:
        mydict[hash_instance[1]].append((str(hash_instance[0]), str(data.recordId)))
    else:
        mydict[hash_instance[1]] = [(str(hash_instance[0]), str(data.recordId))]


r.set("mydict", mydict)
```

Can't find a solution, why the elastic-beanstalk app crashes on aws. It works fine on localhost.

Comment: Do you have logs for elastic-beanstalk app? If yes can you please post the content of log?

Comment: Logs get deleted, as the server crashes... :\

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

Don't use more memory than the specified amount of bytes.
 When the memory limit is reached Redis will try to remove keys
 according to the eviction policy selected (see maxmemory-policy).

If Redis can't remove keys according to the policy, or if the policy is
 set to 'noeviction', Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
 that would use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
 to reply to read-only commands like GET.

This option is usually useful when using Redis as an LRU cache, or to set
 a hard memory limit for an instance (using the 'noeviction' policy).